# How to hide items that the end date has passed on document library?

Tags: sharepoint-2013, share, sharepointdocumentlibrary

I have searched throughout the net but still cannot figured out. I have a SharePoint document library where i have start date and end date. I would like to know how to tell SharePoint to hide the items once the end date has passed?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a view on the list or change default view and filter for startdate >= today and enddate < today. That should do what you want or do you have special requirements?